# Java will not add first integer when computing average

Tags: java

I am new to Java, so I apologize if I am simply overlooking something simple. I wrote this code to make a few simple calculations, but when I run it, Java does not seem to be adding my first integer that is input when calculating the average. Everything else seems to be fine, so I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IntegerCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Enter a list of non-negative integers.");
        System.out.println("Enter a negative number to indicate the end of your input.");

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            int min = keyboard.nextInt();
            int max = min;
            double average = 0;
            double numberOfInt= 1;
            int next = keyboard.nextInt();
            double total = 0;

            while (next > 0){
                if (next > max)
                    max = next;
                else if (next < min)
                    min = next;
                total = total + next;
                numberOfInt++;
                next = keyboard.nextInt();      
            }
            average = total/numberOfInt;

            System.out.println("The largest integer is " + max);
            System.out.println("The smallest integer is " + min);
            System.out.println("The average is " + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on your logic you should set your counter to zero (not one): `double numberOfInt= 0;`

Comment: you read an input twice before starting to operate `total`, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Thank yout Sasha Salauyou. I changed my code to initialize next = min, and then initialized numberOfInt = 0, and that solved the problem. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code does sum all the input numbers, but your `numberOfInt` is off by one.

You should initialize it to

```
double numberOfInt= 0;
```

instead of

```
double numberOfInt= 1;
```

You only want to increment `numberOfInt` when you add the current value of `next` to the `total`, so the first time you add `next` to `total`, `numberOfInt` should become 1.

Comment: To explain why -> you increase ```numberOfInt``` when you enter a negative number too.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see is that inside while loop you have this condition:

```
  if (next > max)
            max = next;
        else if (next < min)
            min = next;
```

Your first value never goes to total.Your first value will count towards average is only when value of next is equal to first value.To solve this problem you can initialize total with max or min(since they are equal initially):

```
double total = (double) max;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This solved my problem. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your int `numberOfInt` should not be initialized at value 1. Since you increment it by 1 with each iteration of your loop, it's value is off by one. Instead, initialize it at value 0.